# Date format is not working properly in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am attempting to format an NSString which looks like:

"8. Juli 2016" (Locale is set as german - "de_DE")

Now i want to show picker with format like:

"juli 8 2106"

on the click of button action datepicker is open and it should display in label as default value.I have written code for it as below :

```
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "de_DE")
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd. MMMM yyyy"
        let currentDateTime = NSDate()
        strDob = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime)
        lblFitnessRed.text=strDob
```

but picker should be shown in "MMMM dd yyyy"
also it there any way to add custom fonts in date picker ?

[image]

Comment: can you clear add custom fonts in date picker

Comment: your date formate is "dd. MMMM yyyy" and you want MMMM dd yyyy?

Comment: i need to display format in label as "dd. MMMM yyyy".and in picker i need to display "MMMM dd yyyy"

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i want to change font name for date picker e.g. "Juli 8 2016"

Comment: You can't customize `UIDatePicker` that way. Use `UIPickerView` and create the columns (views) by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIDatePicker's date format depend on language set for a particular device in setting Or you set locale for date picker in application. If you want your own format then you need to use UIPicker with 3 components(Month, date and year) and set each label text as per your choice. Also you can set label font for your choice as well

Comment: can you please tell how to edit my post so i can put screen shot you will better understand after that

Comment: So want to change the way it show in datepicker, right?. Right now it's MMMM dd YYYY. And you want to show dd MMMM YYYY. right?

Comment: let me explain the format in image is currect but the thing is in picker its not taking locale as german . it is july in picker but it should display july now format is currect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122894/discussion-between-sschunara-and-rahul-anand).

Comment: but when i add code dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "de_DE") it is showing as 8 juli 2016 but i need juli 8 2016. please help